# Eclipse: how to list files not under SVN version control

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

Icons showing the status  of the files are small and sometimes I miss a file on a commit because I forgot to put it under Version Control.
Is ther an easy way of listing the files of project which are not under version control to use before comitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use synchronize  to repository functionality and it will show you all incoming/outgoing changes including list of new files in your local

```
team -> synchronize with repository
```